# In microsoft's latest webchat v4.5.2. how to use a custom STT/ TTS engine like google's. This was possible in v3 using the ISpeech interface

Tags: voice, web-chat

I am using microsoft's latest Botframework-webchat v4.5.2 from https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat. Is there a way to use a custom STT/ TTS like google or watson's STT/TTS. Note this was possible in v3 using the ISpeech interface. Is there an equivalent in v4?

Need to be able to use a custom speech to text, text to speech engine like google's or watson's in webchat v4

In webchat v3 this can achieved by implementing the ISpeechRecognizer and ISpeechSynthesizer interfaces and I was able to use it with google's STT and TTS

Answer (score -1):

There are two samples on the BotFramework-WebChat repo that you should look over:

- [06.c.cognitive-services-speech-services-js](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/06.c.cognitive-services-speech-services-js): Introduces speech-to-text and text-to-speech ability using Cognitive Services Speech Services API.
- [06.f.hybrid-speech](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/06.f.hybrid-speech): Demonstrates how to use both browser-based Web Speech API for speech-to-text, and Cognitive Services Speech Services API for text-to-speech.

Either sample should give you the functionality you are looking for. You can review the complete list of Web Chat samples on their repo, located [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#samples-list).

Hope of help!

Comment: This is the direct opposite of what was asked.